# randomly sample a database using sample_n() with dbplyr

Tags: sql, r, dbplyr

Is it possible to select a random (or pseudo-random) subset from a database using a function like dplyr::sample_n() but in dbplyr or another R package that runs SQL queries?

The purpose is to test queries on small batches before running a time-intensive data pull from the database.

Comment: This might be a workaround for you (https://nuitrcs.github.io/databases_workshop/r/exercises_with_answers.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working for our MySQL server:

```
dbGetQuery(con, 
"SELECT * 
FROM data_table_name 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 500;")
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQLite you may try this :

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;")
```